# How do I set a folder as a Source Folder in Eclipse with Gradle?

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I created a Java project and used Gradle to structure it with a source folder and a build folder with generated files.

Then I checked in the project using Git and checked it out on another computer. But on this second computer, I can't run this Java project since my `src/` folder is not selected as a Source folder. How can I do this? should I have done anything different on the project setup using Gradle?

My `build.gradle` just contains these lines:

```
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'java'
```

When I try to run my computer on my second computer I get this error message:

> Selection does not contain a main type

but it runs well on my first computer.

Comment: Project Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source.

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on your folder -> Build Path -> Use as Source Folder?

Comment: On the second computer, did you either run `gradle eclipse` and "import existing project", or use the STS Gradle plugin and "import Gradle project"?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: I runned `gradle eclipse` and then imported the existing project.

Comment: @Pshemo: Thanks, you should post that as an answer!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

By default, the Java plugin assumes that production sources are located under `src/main/java/`. If they are located under `src/`, you'll have to let Gradle know:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["src"]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jonas You probably should accept this answer instead of mine since it solves your problem using Gradle. Mine answer was more general.

Comment: When a project is new, the dependencies change often, and it's annoying to have to tell Eclipse repeatedly that `scripts` is a source directory. I follow the Gradle/Maven convention, but Groovy scripts that are not supposed to be compiled, but should be runnable and debuggable, go in `scripts`: that _is_ the Groovy convention, which the Groovy plug-in will honor. So add this to every Gradle script:  ```sourceSets {
 main {
  java {
   srcDirs += 'scripts'
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In eclipse , right clik to you project => proporty => java build path =>in source check your folder 
enjoy

Answer (score 2):

Both previous answers are correct but I would also suggest adopting Gradle's convention (Maven's really) as it will save you a lot of time in the future just by being consistent.

Of course, you could always be consistent the other way around and add the custom srcDirs to every project, but it's easy enough to start every project with a:

`$ mkdir -p src/{main,test}/{java,resources}`

Food for thought. :)